# konsole -e does not work anymore

Tags: kubuntu, 17.04, konsole

I just upgraded to kubuntu 17.04 and the ***konsole -e*** does not work anymore.

Using it in a script to simply execute commands in a new window (sort of a user menu)

All was fine on kubuntu 16.04

Any ideas??

Comment: What exactly is it doing?  Does it just open then close the window?  Anymore information that you could add would really help us to help you!

Comment: It seems that for a split second a new terminal window opens up - but closes immediately. No error message or whatever..

Comment: So, does a command like this work:  `konsole -e 'bash -c "ls; bash"'`  ?

Comment: Hmmm...that actually does the trick....

Comment: So I will re-work my menu-script.... Thanks  million!!

Comment: No problem!  Have an awesome day!  =)

Answer (score 1):

According to the `konsole` help command:

```
konsole --help

  -e <cmd>                  Command to execute. This option will catch all following arguments, so use it as the last option.
```

It will run the commands after it.  What it means by `last option`, is that you can do like the following:

```
konsole --fullscreen -e 'bash -c "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade; bash"'
```

Where if you put the `-e` command before the `--fullscreen` you'll get the quick window that will open and close.  So, it has to be after the other options you want to use.  Also, the `; bash` at the end of the command is what tells the system to keep the `konsole` window open after the command completes.

Hope this helps!